# Microphone issues on Dell Precision 5510

Tags: linux, windows, audio, microphone

I have a Dell Precision 5510 laptop (UK model), which has some sort of microphone problem. I don't know when this may have started, as I previously only used audio with an external headset, but now need to use internal audio as well.  I see a lot of posts/articles/etc describing very low volume of the built-in microphone - however this does not seem to be the case for me.

On my laptop, the microphone picks up taps, knocks, etc. very well.  It records key taps on the keyboard as clear distinct "click-click-click" as well as the taps on the touchpad.  However it does not record any spoken voice or music being played. I tried various drivers under Windows (default RealTek, previous old RealTek driver, Microsoft HD Audio driver) - same results.  I booted up from Linux USB - and the same problem is present in Linux as well.

This issue is present in many applications I tried (Skype, Zoom, Teams, etc) as well as in the settings themselves.

I had a look in system BIOS - the only options there are "microphone on/off".

Short of assuming that there is a hardware fault, am I missing something?

Comment: A guess is that the microphone only picks up noise transmitted via or inside the laptop case. It might mean that, if truly functioning, it's somehow isolated from outside noise.

Answer (score 0):

Try *yelling* into the microphone. Many applications, such as Skype and Zoom, have a minimum volume floor, below which background noises are muted *completely*. BTW, Zoom has a good [feature to echo the mic input](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362283-Testing-audio-before-Zoom-Meetings) for testing volume.

If screaming at the mic *does* produce *some* output, you can add a software audio equalizer/amplifier, such [Equalizer APO](https://equalizerapo.com/) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/equalizer-apo/). Boost the mic by 10 or so dB, and equalize to improve speech clarity. (On this laptop, I also use Equalizer APO to amplify and equalize the received audio to make it more understandable on the tiny, tinny speakers.)

That said, this likely would *not* produce a satisfactory audio conference experience if the mic is bad, or poorly located in the laptop -- you'd get fan noise, key clicks and other distractions amplified along with your voice.